# what does "this" reserved word do in C# in parameters field?

Tags: c#, oop, parameters, this

I saw things like this:

```
public static void FunctionSample(**this** Class1 x, int r, double f){
```

what does "this" do?

Answer (score 6):

Ths means an **[extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)** to `Class1`, although in current form its  incorrect since the **method needs to be static** as well and inside a static class.

[Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

> Extension methods are defined as **static methods** but are called by
>   using instance method syntax. Their first parameter specifies which
>   type the method operates on, and the parameter is preceded by the
>   [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dk1507sz.aspx) modifier.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the method you're creating is an extension method. This means (in your case) that the method will act as if it were a member method of `Class1`. So you could just use this:

```
Class1 exmpl = new Class1();
exmpl.FunctionSample(0, 0.0);
```

However, it won't work in your case, since extension methods need to be static, and exist in a static class.

If you want the extension methods to work like the example given above, you will need a `using` directive to the namespace the static class containing the extension methods is in.

In fact, this is how linq works as well. If you add `using System.Linq` to your code file, the only thing you're doing is importing a load of extension methods.